# Создание объекта внутри Job в Quartz.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, quartz

Подскажите, как правильно работать с контекстом базы данных (ef core) внутри Job-ы Quartz.net

Чтобы работать с базой хочу создать `_context` как поле джобы.
Выглядело бы это примерно так:

```
public class LoaderJob:IJob
{
    private PsgrContext _context;
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var q = _context.Photos(); //Тут уже работать с контекстом 
            Console.WriteLine("Execute");
        });
    }

    public LoaderJob()
    {
        _context = new PsgrContext();
        Console.WriteLine("Ctor Test");
    }
}
```

Но к сожалению, такой код:

```
NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"quartz.serializer.type", "binary"}
            };
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

// and start it off
await scheduler.Start();

// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
IJobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.Create<LoaderJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
var jobs = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, IReadOnlyCollection<ITrigger>>();
jobs[job1] = new [] {trigger1};

await scheduler.ScheduleJobs(jobs, true);
```

Вернет такой вывод:

```
Ctor Test
Execute
Ctor Test
Execute
Ctor Test
Execute
Ctor Test
Execute
Ctor Test
Execute
Ctor Test
Execute
```

Я могу передать `_context` в качестве параметров джобы, или использовать статические поля. Но это все не потокобезопасно.

А т.к. работа с базой из разных контекстов потокобезопасна, лучшим решением было бы проинициализировать контекст внутри джобы. Но как это сделать, я не знаю.